# How to get the TextString property of an MText object?

Tags: python, activex, win32com, autocad

I have a very simple AutoCAD drawing with just two entities: an [`MText`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-2532B20E-413D-4F59-9E88-B40E8AABB9FF) object and a `Polyline` object, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Snapshot]

I'd like to programmatically get the [`TextString`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-E54B1951-5BF5-4524-97E6-DFB4E4A20109) property from the `MText` object (i.e. the string `'foo'`) through the following code:

```py
import win32com.client

acad = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('AutoCAD.Application')
dwg = acad.Documents.Open(r'C:\path\to\my\drawing\test.dwg')
ms = dwg.ModelSpace

for obj in ms:
    if obj.EntityName == 'AcDbMText':
        print(obj.TextString)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-299-e8bbc8ec7f92>", line 3, in <module>
    print(obj.TextString)

  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))

AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.AutoCAD 2021 Type Library.IAcadEntity instance at 0x2562970331648>' object has no attribute 'TextString'
```

This is pretty weird because one year ago this code was working nicely. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about programming AutoCAD with Python. From what I know, with the COM/ActiveX API, [MText object](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-2532B20E-413D-4F59-9E88-B40E8AABB9FF) does have a TextString property but there's none EntityName property, you should use [ObjectName](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2019/ENU/?guid=GUID-12879015-C05A-4DF8-8B9C-3C861D098D6B).

Comment: I don't have that problem as `print(obj.EntityName)` outputs `AcDbMText`

Answer (score 0):

The correct method is:

```
import win32com.client

acad = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('AutoCAD.Application')
dwg = acad.Documents.Open(r'C:\path\to\my\drawing\test.dwg')
ms = dwg.ModelSpace

for obj in ms:
    if obj.EntityName == 'AcDbMText':
        mtext = win32com.client.CastTo(obj, "IAcadMText") 
        print(mtext.TextString)
```